# WebSphere MQ MCA user ID

Tags: ibm-mq

I am using WebSphere MQ version 8.0 to create a remote queue.But it asks for MCA User ID.  I am not sure what to enter here. Please help me how to retrieve this.

Comment: maybe you can add 'mqm' as MCAUSERID, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no field on the definition of a QREMOTE object for MCAUSER. Are you perhaps creating a channel definition instead?

If you are creating a channel definition then the MCAUSER field can be used in the following ways:-

- Left blank and allowed to adopt the user ID from the client (not recommended unless you can trust your network setup and thus the client machines).
- **Left blank, and assigned by a CHLAUTH rule (preferred because you can set it dependent on other criteria allowing you to be more convinced a client machine is allowed to connect at all).**
- Left blank, and then set by a security exit (consider if you are pre-V7.1) and can't use the previous bullet).
- Set to a user ID known to the O/S of the queue manager's machine (again not recommended because now all connections to that channel will run with that user ID).

If this doesn't answer, perhaps you can provide a screenshot of exactly what you were doing?